# How to pass rbac information from angular frontend to kotlin backend in azur context

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, rbac, msal-angular

I'm going back to angular and its eco-system and in particular the lib msal. I have a standard application with an angular front end and a java back end. My front end behaves well (connection, disconnection, token renewal, ...). And I can also manipulate the roles.
On the java side, I get a jwt token but it doesn't contain the role information. I would like to add this information in the token, but I do not find how to do it. Maybe my approach is not the right one.

I mainly followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code
I tried several solutions found on google with the keywords msal angular rbac api but without success.
I'm not sure which code to show you, but if you want an overview, you can find my sources here: https://github.com/nacrotic/skillManager

*English is not my first language. Thank you in advance if you take the time to correct my message*